# Why is there a 66 Vac reading on the metal shield of our AC socket?

Tags: ac, circuit-analysis

Today, out of curiosity, I took a measurement between the water pipe (presumably to be ground) and an exposed area of the AC socket with metal shielding (supposedly to be ground as well), and got an AC reading of 66 Volts, and 0.21mA.

Why? I don't understand

Comment: What country? What voltage mains? Practices and regulations vary. I'd expect ~0 id grounded. Is there a ground pin as well or IS this the ground pin? What happens if youn load it with say a 1K resistor or a light bulb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen this happen before.

First: I have to make a couple of assumptions because you didn't include enough information in your question.

I'm assuming that you have a nominal 120 Vac AC Mains supply.

Where I have seen this before is when your outlet is connected to the supply with standard Loomex / Romex 14/2 wire with ground conductor.

The problem is that the ground conductor in the cable is not connected at the source.

The AC voltage that you measured is coming from the capacitive coupling between the AC Hot and Neutral.  Because the ground is about the same distance between each of the insulated conductors, there is about the same amount of capacitance from each of the conductors to the ground wire.  This looks like an approximate 2:1 capacitive voltage divider.

The amount of current that you are measuring says that there is a fair amount of capacitance between the ground wire and the main conductors.  That means that the ground is broken / disconnected quite some distance away from the socket.

If the ground was disconnected right at the AC socket, the voltage wouldn't be quite in the middle like it is now *and* you wouldn't have that much current flowing when you do the current measurement.

Regardless, this is a dangerous situation and needs to be fixed.

If you can't find the broken or disconnected ground wire, run a separate ground wire from the outlet socket to the cold-water pipe that you used during your testing.  Ideally, you would take your ground from the cold-water pipe right when it comes into your building, BEFORE the water meter or shut-off valve.

Comment: Note that the source impedance implied by the voltage and current readings is about 300K ohms, which would be a net effectice capacitance of about 8 nF at 60 Hz, which is a perfectly reasonable value for several dozen feet of romex.

Answer (score 0):

If the exposed part is connected to the earth pin then I suspect that your earthing is faulty and somewhere it touches with the neutral or return of the grid.

Comment: is it possible that the exposed part is actually connected to the neutral, but not to the ground as I think? if so, is it safe? I think a short circuit could put neutral to hot and thus making the metal part dangerous to touch. Am I correct? and even without a short, if I connect a transformer dc adapter to the nearby ac socket, am I connecting the neutral to hot and making it unsafe?